# GUI not showing up, Java (BlueJ)

Tags: java, user-interface, bluej

Creating a Tic Tac Toe game. As of right now, the buttons have no purpose, and the game shouldn't work at all. All I am trying to do is set up the GUI for the game, which shows up sometimes I run it, but most of the time never shows up. I'm quite new to GUI for Java so any information would be helpful!

****EDIT: Figured it out! I had to do `frame.setVisible(true)` after I created all the buttons, seemed to fix it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * A class modelling a tic-tac-toe (noughts and crosses, Xs and Os) game in a very
 * simple GUI window.
 * 
 * @author Thomas Bryk
 * @version December 4, 2016
 */

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame
{ 
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton[][] buttons;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenuItem menuNew, menuQuit;
    private JLabel label;
    private JOptionPane pane;

    /** 
     * Constructs a new Tic-Tac-Toe board and sets up the basic
     * JFrame containing a JTextArea in a JScrollPane GUI.
     */
    public TicTacToe()
    { 
        super();
        frame=new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        JMenu menu=new JMenu("Game");
        label=new JLabel();

        menuBar= new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(menu);

        menuNew= new JMenuItem("New");
        menuNew.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        menuNew.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Creates a new game of Tic Tac Toe");

        menuQuit= new JMenuItem("Quit");
        menuQuit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q,ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        menuQuit.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("Quits the game of Tic Tac Toe");

        menu.add(menuNew);
        menu.add(menuQuit);

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.add(label);
        frame=new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(350,355);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        buttons=new JButton[3][3];
    }

    private void setUp()
    {
        JPanel game = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));  
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(panel);
        game.setVisible(true);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(325,425));
        panel.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);   

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
            {
                buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
                buttons[i][j].setText("");
                buttons[i][j].setVisible(true);
                game.add(buttons[i][j]); 
                buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        TicTacToe mainGame=new TicTacToe();
        mainGame.setUp();
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {     
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally in swing you first create a `JFrame` then a `JPanel`or more if required.
Furthermore you can setup `LayoutManager`for each panel.

You definitely don't need to setup `buttons[i][j].setVisible(true);` or anything similar manualy. You just setVisisible(true) on a Panel or Frame and it will automatically set everything for every component that is attached to that panel/frame.

Also get rid of `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` for now.

Also one thing that is a rather good practice - first set up everything you need for a component before adding it to a panel or frame.

Other than that I have no real idea why it would sometimes show up and other times not.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've changed all the things you told me to, though I still haven't figured out why my buttons wont show up (could be the whole panel?). Any thoughts?

Comment: I see you figured it out. Yeah I didn't notice your frame set visible. Generally you set visibility as the last thing after setting everything up. Good for you. Instead of editing the post insert a new answer. Maybe it will help others.